# Alphabetize list items using interior text

Tags: sorting

I have a list of over 1,000 list items that follow this form:

`<li class="sortable-itemW5">Aken I. Pard F0068UY</li>`

I need to alphabetize these items by **last name**. Unfortunately, the list is FirstName LastName format, and it is surrounded by html tags. Is there a way to organize this list of items by last name, producing a new list, without modifying the items themselves?

I tried using `sort` but can't find anything in the documentation that would allow for this.

Comment: Are you using Javascript with this? And if so, are all the  elements formatted the same way? IE, First name, Middle initial, Last name, ID?

Comment: All the elements are exactly the same format, organized on new lines in a huge list of ~1,500 items. This is just an output text file from another (Pandas) program. I later use the list in a tool that uses Javascript. But it would be very helpful to input them in a alphabetized form first.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a bit hard to "guess" which words are part of the last name and which words are not. For instance, `"Aken I. Pard" -> "Pard"`, `"Robert Downey Jr" -> "Downey"`, `"Edgar Allan Poe" -> "Poe"`, `"Diderik van der Waals" -> "van der Waals"`. You could try using a library dedicated to this problem, for instance https://nameparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's a bit hard to "guess" which words are part of the last name and which words are not. For instance:

```
"Aken I. Pard"          -> "Pard"
"Robert Downey Jr"      -> "Downey"
"Edgar Allan Poe"       -> "Poe"
"Diderik van der Waals" -> "van der Waals"
```

You could try using a library dedicated to this problem, for instance https://nameparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

> Is there a way to organize this list of items by last name, producing a new list, without modifying the items themselves?
>
> I tried using sort but can't find anything in the documentation that would allow for this.

The [documentation for `list.sort` and `sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto) should have told you about the `key` optional argument, to sort a list according to a criterion. For instance:

```py
from nameparser import HumanName

l = ["Aken I. Pard", "Robert Downey Jr", "Edgar Allan Poe", "Diderik van der Waals"]
l.sort(key=lambda x: HumanName(x).last)
print(l)
```

In the `lambda` above you can also include an html parser to remove the `<li></li>` tags and keep only the name string, before passing that name string to nameparser.HumanName.